# I want to create a unique time stamp in oracle, it should check previous time stamp and overwrite if it is previously used?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I want to create a unique time stamp in Oracle, it should check previous time stamp and overwrite if it is previously used. I tried creating one in SQL Server but it doesn't work. Please help

Comment: I'm not sure what "unique timestamp" means to you.  A timestamp is inherently not unique-- two actions could happen at the same instant.  You could have a monotonically increasing sequence and generate a timestamp that is, say, sequence milliseconds after some fixed date (Jan 1, 1970, Jan 1, 2000, Jan 1, 1900, etc.).  That would be unique but the field wouldn't really tell you when something happened...

Comment: I need to create a function like this
1) create a timestamp(p1), store the current timestamp
2) after that it should create another timestamp(p2) and it should compare  with p1, if p1=p2 the function should create a new one with some delay like 00.009 seconds

Comment: You want a single function that generates two local variables, assigns both of them the `systimestamp`, compares the two local variables, waits for 9 milliseconds, and then calls `systimestamp` again to overwrite the value of the second local variable...  Initially, the two variables are almost certainly going to match (particularly if you are running on Windows).

Comment: Can you help me in creating a function(pl\sql code) like you said above

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why you would want to do such a thing.  Your request appears to translate to this

```
create or replace function this_is_silly
  return timestamp
is
  t1 timestamp := systimestamp;
  t2 timestamp := systimestamp;
begin
  if( t1 = t2 )
  then
    dbms_lock.sleep(0.01);
    t2 := systimestamp;
  end if;
  return t2;
end;
```

Maybe instead you are looking for something like

```
create table all_timestamps_returned (
  ts timestamp primary key
);

create or replace procedure get_a_new_timestamp( p_new_ts out timestamp )
as
  l_ts timestamp := systimestamp;
begin
  insert into all_timestamps_returned( ts )
    values( l_ts );
  p_new_ts := l_ts;
exception
  when dup_val_on_index
  then
    dbms_lock.sleep( 0.01 );
    get_a_new_timestamp( p_new_ts );
end;
```

This will iterate (potentially for a number of times in a reasonably busy system) until it happens to get a unique timestamp or you exhaust your max recursion limit.  You could implement this iteratively using a loop as well but then you'd probably want to have some sort of failsafe if you've retried 50 times without getting a unique timestamp.  Again, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this rather than recognizing that multiple events can happen at the same time and using a sequence to generate the unique key.  But you could.

Comment: My guess is,  @gowtham_dontu meant to store the timestamp produced by the function and on a subsequent call ensure that the next timestamp is different from the previous one.